# What is the meaning of (for(t in 2:1000)) in the R code of Random Walk Simulation?

Tags: r

What is the meaning of for(t in 2:1000)?

```
x = e = rnorm(1000)
for (t in 2:1000) x[t] = x[t-1] + e[t]
windows()
plot(x, type="l")
acf(x)
acf(diff(x))
```

Comment: 2:1000 creates a vector, try `v <- 2:1000`. t takes next value in the vector for each iteration.

Comment: It is, of course, that most hallowed of programming constructions: a for-loop. The reason to start at 2 instead of 1 (or 0)  is that indices in R begin with 1 and `t-1` needs to "obey" that convention.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see:

```
for (t in 2:20) { x[t] = x[t-1] + e[t]
print(t)}

[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
[1] 11
[1] 12
[1] 13
[1] 14
[1] 15
[1] 16
[1] 17
[1] 18
[1] 19
[1] 20
```